# Select from table until a given value is found

Tags: mysql

I've searched for quite a while on this and cannot seem to find something that works for me as every similar question is regarding reaching a certain sum of a column.

I am looking for a way to search through records in a table all having a number of common column values - they are not consecutive records in the table, but they must be consecutive records when the common values are factored in - and retrieving all records until one specific column has a different value.

Given the data:

```
PrimaryID   SecondaryID   TertiaryID   Limit       DateTime
   12            9             4           1       2013-03-22 00:00:14
   11            9             4           1       2013-03-22 00:00:13
   10           54            11           0       2013-03-22 00:00:12
    9            9             4           1       2013-03-22 00:00:11
    8            9            23           1       2013-03-22 00:00:10
    7            9             4           1       2013-03-22 00:00:09
    6            9             4           0       2013-03-22 00:00:08
    5            9            16           0       2013-03-22 00:00:07
    4           72            32           0       2013-03-22 00:00:06
    3            9             4           1       2013-03-22 00:00:05
    2            9             4           1       2013-03-22 00:00:04
    1            9             4           0       2013-03-22 00:00:03
```

I am trying to retrieve the records with both SecondaryID=9 and TertiaryID=4 until Limit=0 (ordered by DateTime DESC).

Using PrimaryID 12 as the starting point I would expect the following:

```
PrimaryID   SecondaryID   TertiaryID   Limit       DateTime
   12            9             4           1       2013-03-22 00:00:14
   11            9             4           1       2013-03-22 00:00:13
    9            9             4           1       2013-03-22 00:00:11
    7            9             4           1       2013-03-22 00:00:09
```

And for PrimaryID 3 as the starting point:

```
PrimaryID   SecondaryID   TertiaryID   Limit       DateTime
    3            9             4           1       2013-03-22 00:00:05
    2            9             4           1       2013-03-22 00:00:04
```

Currently I am retrieving every result for SecondaryID=9 and TertiaryID=4 and then looping over it in PHP - and with currently hundreds of results (and growing every week) it is far too slow to work in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized I have been going about this query the wrong way.

Instead of "counting backwards" from a given point in the data to see when the Limit first became =1 in sequence I instead needed to look for the previous occurrence of Limit=0 and then query forwards until my initial PrimaryID.

The resulting query that covers everything I need is

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE SecondaryID='9' AND TertiaryID='4' AND `Limit`='1' AND PrimaryID<='3' AND `DateTime`>= (SELECT `DateTime` FROM table1 WHERE SecondaryID='9' AND TertiaryID='4' AND `Limit`='0' AND PrimaryID<='3' ORDER BY `DateTime` DESC LIMIT 1) ORDER BY `DateTime` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The query will be

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE PrimaryID <= 12(your_id) AND SecondaryID=9 and TertiaryID=4 AND Limit=1 
ORDER BY DateTime DESC
```

It is tested and working

Comment: Sorry, but that will not give the result set I need. For PrimaryID=12 it will also return the rows with PrimaryID 3 & 2, which should not be in the result set I need because the row with PrimaryID=6 has Limit=0.

Comment: I need the query to retrieve all records (matching both SecondaryID and TertiaryID) from one record stepping back in time until a record exists where Limit=0. Essentially I am using the query to determine at what time the Limit field was changed from 0 to 1 to determine when a currently active state began.